# How to get rid of illegal operand error in always_comb block when used "==" operator in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I keep getting the error
illegal operand for operator "==" at the code block below

```
module ALU(input logic oppCode[2:0], input logic [3:0] rf1, input logic [3:0] rf2
    ,output logic [3:0] result, output logic EQ );
    
    
    
    always_comb begin 
        if(oppCode == 3'b010) begin // Problem
            result <= rf1 - rf2;
        end
        
        else if(oppCode == 3'b101) begin // Problem 
            result <= rf1 + rf2;
        end
        
        else if(oppCode == 3'b111) begin // Problem
            EQ <= (rf1 == rf2);
        end 
    end
endmodule
```

What I want to do here, is comparing the `oppCode` with hard coded instruction types. But I keep getting the Illegal operand for "==" error.

"==" is logical comparison operator so why it is not comparing?

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `oppCode` is **unpacked** (`logic oppCode[2:0]`).

You can't compare an unpacked value with a packed value (`3'b010`).

Either make `oppCode` packed `logic [2:0] oppCode` or add an intermediate signal to convert the unpacked oppCode to a packed version with an `always_comb` and a for loop or just manually.

```
logic [2:0] oppCode_packed;
always_comb begin
  for (int i=0; i<3; i++) begin
    oppCode_packed[i] = oppCode[i];
  end
end
```

and then use `oppCode_packed` in your comparisons.

**Piece of advice:** when you declare an unpacked signal, use the number of bits/elements you want: `logic oppCode[3]`. That's more lisible and you'll be less likely to confuse them.